# DragDrop para arquivos .txt Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-n-drop

Gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar Drag and Drop no Windows Forms para arquivos de fora da aplicação, no caso, um .txt(Assim como é possível no WPF). Só achei exemplos utilizando ListBox. Se for possível, como pegar os dados do arquivo arrastado?

Estou utilizando a versão 4.6 do .NET Framework.

Comment: Queria arrastar para para um `TextBox` e mostrar o conteúdo do arquivo?

Comment: Pra um ListBox, porém é um arquivo completo, em formato .txt.

Comment: É um arquivo com dados para preencher um `ListBox`? Ou quer preencher somente somente com o nome do arquivo? Caso queira preencher com o conteúdo da  `ListBox` adicione o conteúdo do arquivo a pergunta.

Comment: É simplesmente ler o arquivo até o final e jogar linha por linha no ListBox.

Comment: @JonathanBarcela Em linhas gerais quer colocar em um listbox o nome do arquivo texto e a quantidade de linhas que ele possui.
Veja se te ajuda https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan, eu imagino que você queira pegar o endereço do arquivo. Bom, para isso você precisa fazer uma verificação se o que está sendo arrastado é de fato um arquivo com o Evento DragOver

```
private void TextBox_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link;
 else
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}
```

Em seguida quando for solto o arquivo dentro do TextBox (Evento DragDrop) você cria uma string com o arquivo

```
private void TextBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  string arquivo = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string;
  TextBox.Text = arquivo;
}
```

Em suma é isso boa sorte.

Fonte:
 http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2015/03/11/implementando-drag-and-drop-arrastar-e-soltar-em-aplicacoes-windows-forms-com-c/

Comment: Cara tente responder mostrando o trecho do código , dessa forma que você respondeu ele não e permitido aqui no sopt. nesse caso você pode usar o cometário .

Comment: Eu tenho um Código Muito parecido com o que o guilherme Postou e funciona desta forma e acho que atende a pergunta.